# Is there a shorter way of exporting python nested dictionary to CSV?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a nested dictionary which comprises of multiple lists and dictionaries. The "Stations" key contains contains the values which I want to convert to CSV file. I am only after the certain values. A snippet of the dictionary is as below:

```
data = { "brands": {...},
  "fueltypes": {...},
  "stations": {"items": [
      {
        "brandid": "",
        "stationid": "",
        "brand": "Shell",
        "code": "2126",
        "name": "Cumnock General Store",
        "address": "31 Obley St, CUMNOCK NSW 2867",
        "location": {
          "latitude": -32.928744,
          "longitude": 148.755153
        },
        "state": "NSW"
      },
      {
        "brandid": "",
        "stationid": "",
        "brand": "Shell",
        "code": "2200",
        "name": "Tea Tree Cafe",
        "address": "160 Mount Darragh Rd, SOUTH PAMBULA NSW 2549",
        "location": {
          "latitude": -36.944277,
          "longitude": 149.845399
        },
        "state": "NSW"
      }....]}}
```

In order to obtain certain values in "Stations" key, I created blank lists for each of those values and appended accordingly. After that I used the ZIP function to combine the list and converted to a CSV. The Code that I have used is as below:

```
Station_Code = []
Station_Name = []
Latitude = []
Longitude = []
Address = []
Brand = []

for k,v in data["stations"].items():
    for item in range(len(v)):
        Station_Code.append(v[item]["code"])
        Station_Name.append(v[item]["name"])
        Latitude.append(v[item]["location"]["latitude"])
        Longitude.append(v[item]["location"]["longitude"])
        Address.append(v[item]["address"])
        Brand.append(v[item]["brand"])

        #print(f'{v[item]["code"]} - {v[item]["name"]} - {v[item]["location"]["latitude"]}')

rows = zip(Station_Code, Station_Name, Latitude, Longitude, Address, Brand )
with open("Exported_File.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Is there any other alternate/short ways of extracting this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/), there's a fairly easy way to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert dict to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data["stations"]["items"])

# 'location' is a dict, so we need to extract the 'latitude' and 'longitude'.
df['latitude'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x['latitude'])
df['longitude'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x['longitude'])

# Select subset of columns for final csv
df = df[['code', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'address', 'brand']]

df.to_csv('exported-file.csv', index=False, header=False)
```